# How to use multiplication, accretion, percent with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

all

i have followed code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#x_Harga, #x_Jumlah").keyup(function () {
       var Harga = parseInt($('#x_Harga').val());
       var Jumlah = parseInt($('#x_Jumlah').val());
       var PPH = parseInt($('#x_PPH').val());       
       var Total_harga_1 = (Harga * Jumlah) * (PPH / 100);
       var Total_harga = (Harga * Jumlah) + Total_harga1;
       $("#x_Total").val(Total_harga);    
    }); 
});
```

when i put 
harga : 100
jumlah : 10
pph : 10 (10%)
Total harga : 1100 <-- this the result

But the code is dosent work

Comment: what do you mean the code doesn't work

Comment: Probably because you have a naming issue, `Total_harga1` vs `Total_harga_1`. Also why this has nothing to do with php

Answer (score -1):

It's because you named the variable `Total_harga_1` but used `Total_harga1`.